# iOS - Getting a new access token with different scopes from another protected resource

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-msal

In our app, we are calling many endpoints using an access token. Now, the backend is splitting its service into multiple to be able to use Azure's features fully. And they all have different scopes and are their own protected resource.

In the app, we of course only want to manage one token.

In the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-ios-app#call-to-a-web-api it is stated:

If the access token's scope doesn't match the web API's scope, the authentication library obtains a new access token with the correct scope.

There is no more documentation around this, how is this token received back? I was thinking acquireTokenSilently would be called due to the MSAL library integration, but it's not called.

Where is this token received first of all?
Secondly, how should we handle the token(s) for multiple different backend services if they all require different scopes?

Thank you in advance!